# How to activate new Windows 10 installation on the same Hardware?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hp-pavilion

I have a Newly-installed-windows-10 on my machine due to corruptions made to the previous one by a Trojan. I have no idea what my product key and activation keys were, Is there a way I can retrieve my product and activation keys from Microsoft by providing accurate hardware info?

Comment: Do you need them? Most individual-license Windows 10 installations don't.

Comment: Yes, some functions and settings are greyed out and a prompt appears on my screen to reactivate

Comment: Did the previous OS have a legitimate activation, was it OEM or retail or free upgrade from older release? Did you install the same type (Pro vs Home) as you had before? Have you used a Microsoft Account on the previous installation? [Note that there is generally no such a thing as "activation key" in Windows, only the product key.]

Comment: made a mistake about that, Yes the previous installation was the one that legitimately came with the device although the new one I have installed is windows 10 pro the previous was home

Comment: Ah, so you won't be able to obtain the product key because you never had a Pro license in the first place.

Comment: I  plan to revert back to home with windows 10 installation setup but I have no idea on how to retrieve the activation keys

Comment: You can't retrieve the activation keys for Pro because this system doesn't have a Pro license. If you install Home instead, you probably won't _need_ the keys – Win10 usually reactivates hardware-bound licenses automatically.